# cache selectors which were pushed to an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance

I have a website with lots of divs:

```
var cubes = [];
var allCubes = '';
for(var i = 0; i < 857; i++) {
    var randomleft = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000),
        randomtop = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000);
    allCubes += '<div id="cube'+i+'" class="cube" style="position: absolute; left: '+randomleft+'px; top: '+randomtop+'px; width: 7px; height: 7px; z-index: -1"></div>';
}  

$('body').append(allCubes);
```

I want to animate every single div with css3-transition, therefore I'm doing another loop to give them all an ID.

```
for(var i = 0; i < 857; i++) { 
    cubes.push($('#cube'+i));   
}
```

But how can I cache all the `$('#cubeX')` in variables? Wouldn't it be recommended to do that, because I'm doing lots of animations with it.

Cheers

Comment: Tip: For speed, don't use `str += "more"` in a big loop. Instead, do `var str = []; for (…) str.push(more); str = str.join();` Otherwise you're creating tons of unnecessary intermediary strings that have to be garbage collected.

Comment: @Phrogz sorry but I dont get it. Im not the best javascripter. Would it be to cheeky if I ask you to make a fiddle of what I exactly I have to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to cache the objects, in this case you can use an object like

```
var cubes = {};
var allCubes = '';
for (var i = 0; i < 857; i++) {
    var randomleft = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000),
        randomtop = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
    allCubes += '<div id="cube' + i + '" class="cube" style="position: absolute; left: ' + randomleft + 'px; top: ' + randomtop + 'px; width: 7px; height: 7px; z-index: -1"></div>';
}

$('body').append(allCubes);
for (var i = 0; i < 857; i++) {
    cubes['cube' + i] = $('#cube' + i)
}

function getCube(index){
    var cube = cubes['cube' + index];
    if(!cube){
        cube = $('#cube' + index);
        cubes['cube' + index] = cube;
    }
    return cube;
}

//then you can access the cubes via
getCube(1)
getCube(2)
getCube(3)
```

Comment: @supersize no it won't.... but if you are using the selector 1000s of times then it may give a slight performance

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving them all a unique id, just add the same class to all of them - or use the existing `cube` class. then you can just select everything with that class for the animation.

```
var toAnimate = $('.cube');
```

Comment: thanks for that hint, but classes are much more performance consuming than select element directly with IDs. And I want to perform it as good as possible.